# Filter through multiple levels nested array

Tags: javascript

I have a `list` which could look like this:

```
let list = [
  {
    name: "Level 1",
    children: [
      {
        name: "Level 2",
        children: [
          {
            name: "Level 3A",
            children: [],
          },
          {
            name: "Level 3B",
            children: [],
          },
          {
            name: "Level 3C",
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

As you can see it consists of elements with 2 properties: `name` and `children`.
This is simple list but it can be nested many levels down and each element could have a lot of children.

Moreover i have sample array of arrays of strings like this:

```
const filterRows = [
    ["Level 1", "Level 2", "Level 3A"],
    ["level 1", "Level 2", "Level 3C"]
]
```

Each of this 2 arrays of strings represents each 'row' in my list. (Here we don't have `["level 1", "Level 2", "Level 3B"]`)

My goal is to make something like filter. So based on `filterRows` i want my list to be:

```
let filteredList = [
    {
      name: "Level 1",
      children: [
        {
          name: "Level 2",
          children: [
            {
              name: "Level 3A",
              children: [],
            },
            {
              name: "Level 3C",
              children: [],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

As you can see in `filteredList` we only have rows specified in `filterRows` (so here we don't have "Level 3B")

Could you help me create function to do that?

As i said `list` (initial list) could be much more complicated I simplify it. Also `filterRows` can be different (but always correctly represent some rows in our `list`). So it cannot be hardcoded.

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far.  Any progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With matching strings, you could build a tree and rebuild the structure with the wanted items.

```js
const
    filter = level => (r, { name, children }) => {
        const next = level[name];
        if (next) {
            if (Object.keys(next).length) children = children.reduce(filter(next), []);
            r.push({ name, children });
        }
        return r;
    },
    list = [{ name: "Level 1", children: [{ name: "Level 2", children: [{ name: "Level 3A", children: [] }, { name: "Level 3B", children: [] }, { name: "Level 3C", children: [] }] }] }],
    filterRows =  [["Level 1", "Level 2", "Level 3A"], ["Level 1", "Level 2", "Level 3C"]],
    tree = filterRows.reduce((r, a) => {
        a.reduce((o, k) => o[k] ??= {}, r);
        return r;
    }, {}),
    result = list.reduce(filter(tree), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: works almost fine, when we have e.g. ["Level 1"] in filterRows it should return all nested elements in "Level 1". Now it returns only "Level 1", but it not returns all its children. Could you change it? Thank you in advance